# While creating a backup in sql server using query i am getting the following error?

Tags: sql, database-backups

i have a database named students. for that i can able to create the database using the tool backup. but i am not able to create  using the query.

---

```
use students 
go 
backup database students to disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup' with format, medianame = 'test',name = 'back  up of the student database' 
go
```

---

while doing this i am getting the following errror.
could any one help me in this issue?
thank you all/......

***Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the filename of the backup

e.g `` `TO DISK='C:\Backups\BackupFile.BAK' ``

[See MSDN for a full description of options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)